# How to add certain email addresses to allowed list to access my private youtube videos using Youtube Data API?

Tags: php

Is there any way to add a list of email addresses through the YouTube Data API to allow the access to private videos?

Comment: Have you read the API documentation?

Comment: Yes, but didn't get the solution.